# Travis special requirements for each python version

Tags: python, travis-ci, requirements.txt

I need unittest2 and importlib for python 2.6 that is not required for other python versions that travis tests against.

Is there a way to tell Travis-CI to have different requirements.txt files for each python version?

Comment: You may want to switch the correct answer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/36978898/99834

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The proper way to define [conditional requirements](https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is:

```
# requirements.txt
ordereddict; python_version == '2.6'
```

Yep, comments can be used to specify conditional requirements. If you get some errors you may be using an outdated version of pip.

Comment: Recommend this link instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35614580/119527

Answer (score 54):

Travis CI adds an environment variable called `$TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION` that can be referenced in your .travis.yml:

```
python:
  - 2.6
  - 2.7
  - 3.2
  - 3.3
  - pypy
install:
  - if [[ $TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION == 2.6 ]]; then pip install importlib unittest2; fi
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This would cause `unittest2` and `importlib` to be installed only for Python 2.6, with requirements.txt being installed for all versions listed. You can do as many of these checks as necessary. Tornado's [.travis.yml](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/.travis.yml) file uses it quite a bit.