# Is there a way to have a conditional requirements.txt file for my Python application based on platform?

Tags: python, pip

I have a python application that I wrote to be compatible with both, Linux and Windows platforms. However there is one problem... One of the python packages I need for Windows is not compatible with Linux. Fortunately there is another package that provides the same functionality on Linux. All other dependencies are compatible in both platforms.

I know I could have 2 separate requirement files to address both platform dependencies separately. Something like win_requirements.txt and linux_requirements.txt, however this approach doesn't feel like the best way to do it.

I wonder if there is a way I can have only one requirements.txt file so any user can use `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install all the dependencies regardless of what platform they are?

Maybe something like??:

```
SOAPpy>=0.12.22
pycrypto>=2.6.1
suds>=0.4
Python-ldap>=2.4.19
paramiko>=1.15.2
nose>=1.3.4
selenium>=2.44.0
bottle>=0.12.8
CherryPy>=3.6.0
pika>=0.9.14
if platform.system() == 'Linux':
    wmi-client-wrapper>=0.0.12
else if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    WMI>=1.4.9
```

Comment: Strongly recommend looking at Tony G's answer instead of the accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35614580/872328

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could create an `install.py` script and call `pip` by script.

```
import pip

_all_ = [
    "SOAPpy>=0.12.22",
    "pycrypto>=2.6.1",
    "suds>=0.4",
    "Python-ldap>=2.4.19",
    "paramiko>=1.15.2",
    "nose>=1.3.4",
    "selenium>=2.44.0",
    "bottle>=0.12.8",
    "CherryPy>=3.6.0",
    "pika>=0.9.14",
]

windows = ["wmi-client-wrapper>=0.0.12",]

linux = ["WMI>=1.4.9",]

darwin = []

def install(packages):
    for package in packages:
        pip.main(['install', package])

if __name__ == '__main__':

    from sys import platform

    install(_all_) 
    if platform == 'windows':
        install(windows)
    if platform.startswith('linux'):
        install(linux)
    if platform == 'darwin': # MacOS
        install(darwin)
```

Another way to resolve this issue using only `requirements` files should be using inheritance of `requirements`

requirements.txt

```
SOAPpy>=0.12.22
pycrypto>=2.6.1
suds>=0.4
Python-ldap>=2.4.19
paramiko>=1.15.2
nose>=1.3.4
selenium>=2.44.0
bottle>=0.12.8
CherryPy>=3.6.0
```

windows.txt

```
-r requirements.txt
WMI>=1.4.9
```

linux.txt

```
-r requirements.txt
WMI>=1.4.9
```

Then you can call just the requirement equivalent to platform.

```
pip install -r windows.txt
pip install -r linux.txt
```

Comment: In additon, one may want to keep the install.py cleaner by replacing the all block with a base_requirements.txt file and using  -r base_requirements.txt  at the top of the different requirements files.

Comment: pip.main() is deprecated now. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50255019/7234896

Comment: if you have '-r requirements.txt',  and requirements has 'WMI>=1.4.9', while windows.txt has an earlier version 'WMI>=1.4.8', will it down grade the version?

Comment: @mike01010 take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33812968/841339)

Answer (score 332):

You can add certain conditional requirements after a semi-colon. Particularly useful for sys_platform and python_version.

Examples:

```
atomac==1.1.0; sys_platform == 'darwin'
futures>=3.0.5; python_version < '3.0'
futures>=3.0.5; python_version == '2.6' or python_version=='2.7'
```

Apparently you can also exclude particular versions of a library:

```
futures>=3.0,!=3.0.5
```

They are defined in [PEP 508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/) and [PEP 0345 (Environment Markers)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0345/#environment-markers) but the syntax appears to follow the draft [PEP 0496](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0496/).

Comment: is it possible to query for pypy too?

Comment: Actually, I believe its PEP 508.

Comment: @ sebix yes have a look at the PEP.

Comment: Does not seem to work with hash pinning: if I have the line `enum34==1.1.6 --hash=sha256:644837f692e5f550741432dd3f223bbb9852018674981b1664e5dc339387588a; python_version < '3.4'` I get `Expected sha256 644837f692e5f550741432dd3f223bbb9852018674981b1664e5dc339387588a;`, `Got        644837f692e5f550741432dd3f223bbb9852018674981b1664e5dc339387588a`, if I add a space before the `;`, the version condition is just ignored.

Comment: Would there be a way to check if a user uses ssh or https to install packages from git? And depending on that provide a different link to install a package from a private git repo? Or do something like try except?

Comment: @SimoneBronzini try : enum34==1.1.6; python_version < '3.4' --hash=sha256:644837f692e5f550741432dd3f223bbb9852018674981b1664e5dc339387588a

Comment: For PyPy: `platform_python_implementation == "PyPy"`

Answer (score 16):

You can add additional requirements to any package after a semicolon. You may limit any package with multi-condition by `and`, `or`. more conditions: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers

examples:

```
futures>=3.0.5; python_version < '3.0'
futures>=3.0.5; python_version == '2.6' or python_version=='2.7'
futures>3 ; python_version >= "3.6" and sys_platform == "linux"
futures>3.3 ; python_version >= "3.6" and sys_platform == "darwin"
```

Comment: Thanks, the enivironment markers helped. I needed to use os_name to check if it is raspberrypi

Answer (score 10):

Use this in the requirements.txt file

```
uwsgi==2.0.18; platform_system != "Windows"
```

in this case pip will install uwsgi if not running on Windows

Answer (score 2):

A Complimentary questions though, What if none of the default markers is suitable for our usecase.
For example, if I want to install a package when it is run in CI vs when it runs on my machine , Can I set an environment variable and decideds based on its value ?