# What is the right/secure way to pip install a private git repo on a Heroku app?

Tags: git, github, heroku, pip

App structure (Python FastAPI):

```
-my_app
  -server.py
  -Procfile
  -requirements.txt
```

In order to install a private git repo required by my Heroku app, I added the following line to my `requirements.txt`:

```
git+https://<github-token>@github.com/me/my-private-repo.git
```

However on pushing, Github emailed me to say that since I had exposed my token in a commit it had revoked the token. (My app repo is private.) Totally fair! However, my Heroku build now fails, since it prompts for a password when attempting to install the private repo.

I've searched SO/the internet many times re: private repos, but have always come across conflicting suggestions.

Would be grateful to hear what is best practice in this case, for **safely installing a private repo in an automated build**.

What I've tried so far:

- `git+git://username:password@github.com/me/myrepo.git` instead of token obviously has the same issue
- `git+ssh://git@github.com/me/myrepo.git` - yields error `Host key verification failed.`
- Store username:password (or token) as Heroku environment variables - seems from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35353586/6220759) that this isn't possible with `pip`

To expand on the `ssh` option, the following work on my local machine:

- `pip3 install git+ssh://git@github.com/me/my_private-repo.git`
- `git clone https://github.com/me/my_private-repo.git`

However when my `requirements.txt` contains `git+ssh://git@github.com/me/my_private-repo.git`, my Heroku build returns `Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`

Comment: Which one of those conflicting suggestions did you try and why they don't satisfy you?

Comment: expanded the question to include this

Comment: `Host key verification failed.` can be [easily fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13364116/7976758): `ssh-keygen -R github.com; ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssh%5D+Host+key+verification+failed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally got it to work. I'm indebted to Michel Blancard's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50721757/6220759) and associated [gist](https://gist.github.com/michelbl/a6163522d95540cf0c8b6667bd35d5f5), and Bo Jeanes' [custom buidpack](https://github.com/bjeanes/ssh-private-key-buildpack):

In `requirements.txt`:

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/me/my-private-repo.git
```

Convert my private SSH key to the (old) PEM format for Heroku(!):

```
ssh-keygen  -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -m PEM -p
```

(Credit due to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61095760/6220759))

Add private SSH key as Heroku variable:

```
heroku config:set BUILDPACK_SSH_KEY="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa)"
```

Add [this](https://github.com/bjeanes/ssh-private-key-buildpack) custom buildpack to run before the Python buildpack which enables a private SSH key:

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ssh-key.git
```

Deploy!

Comment: The original buildpack is unmaintained now, use the one on the heroku org: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ssh-key, docs: https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ssh-key