# How can I pip install whl file according to current operating system?

Tags: python, pip

I am using a python package that requires a `.whl` package to get pip installed.

However, each operating system has it's own `.whl` file.

Examples

- `linux`: `PyAAF-1.0.0-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`
- `mac`: `PyAAF-1.0.0-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.whl`

Is there a way to set my `requirements.txt` file choose the correct `.whl` file according to the currently-running OS?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to have a conditional requirements.txt file for my Python application based on platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222269/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-conditional-requirements-txt-file-for-my-python-applica)

Answer (score 0):

When you install packages with pip it will automatically set the wheels that your operating system supports. So just type:

```
pip install PackagName
```

In order to install the package. Make sure to not include the version nor the plataform. So if you want to install the latest numpy wheel (numpy-1.14.0-cp27-cp27m-manylinux1_i686.whl) you have to type:

```
pip install numpy
```

And the package will be automatically downloaded from [Pypi](https://pypi.org/)

Note if you want to know which wheel formats your os supports you can open a python console and execute the following code:

```
import pip; print(pip.pep425tags.get_supported())
```