# Generic requirements.txt for TensorFlow on both Apple M1 and other devices

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, apple-m1, requirements.txt

I have a new MacBook with the Apple M1 chipset. To install tensorflow, I follow the instructions [here](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/), i.e., installing `tensorflow-metal` and `tensorflow-macos` instead of the normal `tensorflow` package.

While this works fine, it means that I can't run the typical `pip install -r requirements.txt` as long as we have `tensorflow` in the `requirements.txt`. If we instead include `tensorflow-macos`, it'll lead to problems for non-M1 or even non-macOS users.

Our library must work on all platforms. Is there a generic install command that installs the correct TensorFlow version depending on whether the computer is a M1 Mac or not? So that we can use a single `requirements.txt` for everyone?

Or if that's not possible, can we pass some flag/option, e.g., `pip install -r requirements.txt --m1` to install some variation?
What's the simplest and most elegant solution here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this post [Is there a way to have a conditional requirements.txt file for my Python application based on platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222269/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-conditional-requirements-txt-file-for-my-python-applica)

You can use conditionals on your requirements.txt, thus

```
tensorflow==2.8.0; sys_platform != 'darwin' or platform_machine != 'arm64'
tensorflow-macos==2.8.0; sys_platform == 'darwin' and platform_machine == 'arm64'
```

Comment: Great, I'll try and accept the answer when it works. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, this checks for the OS, not for the architecture, right? Thus, it fails on Intel MacBooks.

Comment: You also need to check the architecture with `platform_machine`. I updated your answer.