# How do I specify a Python version constraint for a dependency specifically for a platform?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

My Python package requires Python >= 3.8 (defined in `setup.cfg` or `pyproject.toml`):

```
python_requires = >=3.8
```

However, it also has the following *optional* dependency :

```
tensorflow>=2.7.0
```

If optional dependencies are tob be installed, I would like to require Python < 3.11 on macOS only. Previously, I tried:

```
tensorflow>=2.7.0;python_version<'3.11'
```

But that contrains Python on all platforms. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: How can a dependency be optionnal ? If I was to use your library, would I need it or not ?

Comment: My package is not a library. This optional dependency is not required for its main functionality, but if you install it, you get additional functionality. I don't want to make it mandatory, because it is a huge dependency and not everyone is going to use it.

Comment: @Itération122442 - Easily, an application feature behind a paywall for example

Comment: @Itération122442: Optional dependencies [are in fact a thing](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#optional-dependencies) in Python package distribution.

Comment: `tensorflow>=2.7.0; python_version<'3.11' and sys_platform=='darwin'` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35614580/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+platform The problem is that `tensorflow` will always be installed when the condition is met, `pip` cannot consult existing packages to decide what to install.

Comment: It seems like I need to add `tensorflow>=2.7.0; sys_platform != 'darwin'` to make this work, right?

Comment: @cbrnr If it's `tensorflow>=2.7.0` in both cases you don't need a conditional dependency. Just always install `tensorflow>=2.7.0`.

Comment: It's the same dependency, but if on macOS, Python needs to be restricted to < 3.11. As explained in the accepted answer, this is currently not possible and can just be worked around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to specify [setup.cfg' `python_requires`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html) or [pyproject.toml' `requires-python`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/#requires-python) in terms of the package dependencies. Just the otherway around: you can specify dependencies in terms of the Python version using [environment markers](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/dependency-specifiers/#environment-markers) as the example you mentioned in the question.

If you want to workaround this limitation of the Python packaging system, one possible way is to create 2 separated packages:

- "pkg A", with the basic dependencies, `python_requires = >=3.8`, and without `tensorflow`.
- "pkg B", with `tensorflow` and "pkg A" as dependencies and `python_requires = <=3.11`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected. A bit unwieldy, but better than not being able to do it at all!

Comment: There are other "clever ways" of achieving that...
For example, in the same "extra" group that you specify `tensorflow` as a optional dependency, you could add another dependency that has `python_requires = <=3.11` (you can create an empty package for that). This will force the depency resolution algorithm to fail if the conditions are not mat and the installation to halt. But 2 packages looks more clean to me.