# getting an error while running docker compose for first time

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, requirements.txt

I'm trying to setup Docker for my first time ever and I've encountered the following error while running the command: docker compose up --build

```
8.892 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==306 (from versions: none)
8.893 ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==306
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python","manage.py","runserver"]`
```

requirements.txt:

```
asgiref==3.7.2
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
certifi==2024.2.2
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
Django==4.2.11
docker==7.0.0
idna==3.6
packaging==24.0
pywin32==306
requests==2.31.0
sqlparse==0.4.4
typing_extensions==4.10.0
tzdata==2024.1
urllib3==2.2.1
```

More info:

after running pip show pywin32
got the following version:
Name: pywin32
Version: 306

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

`python:3` base image is a docker image based on `debian:12`, a linux distribution.

`pywin32` on the other hand has only [Windows releases](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/306/#files), which makes a lot of sense for it being a package with the description "Python for Win32 extensions".

Hence you get the error `ERROR: No matching distribution found`. The architectures are incompatible.

### Solutions

As for what to do for this, these are basically your options.

1. Do you really need the package? If not, remove it.
2. Are you building something that is cross-platform and uses `pywin32` only conditionally? Use

```
pywin32==306; platform_system=="Windows"
```

See also [Is there a way to have a conditional requirements.txt file for my Python application based on platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222269/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-conditional-requirements-txt-file-for-my-python-applica) for other options.

3. Are you building something that needs to run on windows? Don't use a linux container.

Comment: I'm actually just starting to really programmer after studying cs. and this moment just practicing. it worked. Thanks a lot!